# How to find "content files" within a publishsinglefile .exe context (with unknow TEMP folder)

Tags: .net, publish

**EDIT**
Actually I was wrong, I got a false diagnostic of my issue.

There were indeed a [bug](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/3704) in .Net Core 3+ with SingleFile publishing with `AppContext.BaseDirectory`. But it is fixed now in .Net 5.

I saw it when enabling a primitive log system when my WPF is closing to debug the published application.

The mistake I made was using pack URI to access my content files.

This pack URI always work as a relative path from execution, so from the temporary extracted folder in case of SingleFile publishing, resulting in not finding the content file stored in `AppContext.BaseDirectory`.

So I had to remove using pack URI (Appending `pack://application:,,,` to the relative path) and use an absolute path (`Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,@MyContentFile)`) instead.

For the record here was my question :

> I have my WPF application that run. I have both ressource files and
> content files (some config and modifiable from user icons files).
>
> When I publish it (via `dotnet publish`) it work. But when I publish
> it as a single file (via `-p:PublishSingleFile=true` parameter) then,
> as I understand [here](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2019/09/22/single-file-exes-in-net-core/), The resulting application is silently
> extracted in a "random" temporary folder. So using my previously
> `Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory,@MyContentFile)` doesn't work
> as `AppContext.BaseDirectory` now point to this temporary, unknown
> from me, folder.
>
> How can I get the path of my SingleFile, which is the root of my
> relative content files, at runtime, so from this unknown temporary
> extracted folder.
>
> Thanks.